# Type mismatch in NotesDatabase.Search method using vb

Tags: vb.net, lotus-notes

I need to search a notes database with a set of given criteria using VB. I was going through IBM documentation at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_EXAMPLES_SEARCH_METHOD.html
and came up with below code as per example no. 3 there:

```
    Dim notesSession As Object = CreateObject("lotus.NotesSession")
    notesSession.Initialize(Password)
    Dim notesDatabase As Object = notesSession.GETDATABASE(ServerName, DatabaseName)
    Dim Query as String = "{Form = Project}"
    Dim notesDocumentCollection As Object = notesDatabase.Search(Query, Nothing, 0)
    Dim notesDocument As Object = notesDocumentCollection.GetFirstDocument
```

But at *notesDatabase.Search(Query, Nothing, 0)* it gives me a runtime exception saying a type mismatch. Using *Nothing and 0* for 2nd and 3rd arguments are fine as per https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/it/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_SEARCH_METHOD.html

Therefore I suspect I am doing something wrong with first argument of

> notesDocumentCollection = notesDatabase .Search( formula$ ,
>   notesDateTime , maxDocs% )

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your Formula is wrong. It needs to be "Form = ""Project""". In addition: I never saw code, where Dim and assignment was in the same line... I had no idea, that this is valid code in vb.net

Comment: Thanks, changing formula worked. But had to change Argument 2 from Nothing to New Runtime.InteropServices.UnknownWrapper(Nothing) to avoid the exception. Yes it is valid and works in vb :)

Comment: You should add the above comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Formula is wrong. It needs to be

```
"Form = ""Project"""
```

In Addition the concept of "Nothing" seems to be different between the COM- Classes and vb.net as you found out when trying: You need to use a parameter of the right type. In your case:

```
New Runtime.InteropServices.UnknownWrapper(Nothing)
```

instead of simply

```
Nothing
```

as your second parameter.